# psycopg2 Only Displays First Row of Postgresql Database

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I am running Python3.5 and Psycopg2 2.6 in a tkinter window. 
I have this function in a file called backend.py

```
import psycopg2


def search(year=0, month=0):
    '''Search the database for entries.'''
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='birth_years'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM birthdays WHERE year=year OR month=month;")
    row = cur.fetchone()
    conn.close()
    return row
```

I have frontend.py with this code.

```
from tkinter import *
import backend


def search_command(year, month):
    '''Run queries on the database.'''
    listbox1.delete(0, END)
    row = backend.search(year_text.get(), month_text.get())
    listbox1.insert(END, row)

window = Tk()
window.wm_title("Birthdays")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

Grid.rowconfigure(window, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(window, 0, weight=1)

b1 = Button(window, text="Search", width=15, command=search_command)
b1.grid(row=2, column=5)


window.mainloop()
```

Database:

```
    id year month

    1 1999 2
    2 2005 5
    3 1987 11
    4 1988 12
    5 1978 10
```

The postgresql database contains this data. PGAdmin2 is able to run the query fine and select only the row that I want. When I run a query for the year 1988 using the function all I get in the first row of the database.

```
1 1999 2
```

Comment: Errr, yeah, because you use `row = cur.fetchone()` and not `fetchall()`. You explicitly ask it to only return one value.

Comment: Although there is something else to the question, since you apparently query for 1988 and get back a result for 1999? Is that a typo or a real issue?

Comment: It does not matter if I use cur.fetchone() or cur.fetchall(), I get the same result. It only fetches the first row of the database. No typos, if I search for 2005 I get 1999. This does not make sense.

Comment: cur.fetchall() just gets the entire database.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a logic error but I can't test specifically to be sure.

Your query is currently:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM birthdays WHERE year=year OR month=month;")
row = cur.fetchone()
```

There's two issues with this:

1. You used `fetchone()` instead of `fetchall()` so it's clear that you'll only ever get one result; that's what you asked for.
2. Your query is just a simple string. You haven't actually passed any arguments to your function into the query. *Every* row has a value in `year` that is equal to that value in `year` (you're asking each value to compare itself to itself) meaning your query is always `True` for all rows (so you'll pull the whole database). Caveat: There may be NaN-type values where this is not true, but on-the-whole it is.

Try:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM birthdays WHERE year=%s OR month=%s;", (year, month))
row = cur.fetchone()
```

You may need to enclose the `%s` placeholders in quotation marks, I can't test and don't know your database setup. This is a parameterized query, where `year` and `month` are dynamic based on the values passed to the function. You *could* do this through string formatting (you'll see a *lot* of people doing this in questions here) but that really exposes you to SQL injection: remember [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).